# If, elif and else - ask only for strings, continue the loop if the user enters a number

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have been wondering this for a longer time
If I check for user input, I know how to check for strings.
But what if I want to check if the user has entered just integers or floats. I tried it with an "if name == int or float: block but of course that didn't work. Can you help me out?
How do I check for that? Here is my code. Of course the input I always converted to a string so I don't know how to do that.

```
print("Enter a name: ")
while True:
    name = input()
    if name != "":
        print("Thank you for entering a name: ")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
```

I also tried this:

```
print("Enter a name: ")
while True:
    name = input()
    if type(name) != int:
        print("Thats not a name!")
        print("Now please enter a name without numbers")
    elif type(name) != float:
        print("Thats also not a name!")
        print("Now please enter a name without numbers")
    elif type(name) != "":
        print("Thank you for entering your name!")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: This might help.

```py
def hello(userinput):
    if userinput.isdigit():
        print("You entered a number. That's not valid!")
    else:
        print("You entered a valid name.")
```

#### Old Solution

```py
print("Enter a name: ")
while True:
    name = input()
    if type(name) != int:
        print("Thank you for entering a name: ")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
```

Also I can understand why you did that.
The previous code you created meant that if the user typed the class int. This will be impossible to type a class because `input()` only takes a string from the user's input.

Comment: so how can i solve this?

Comment: Use a try/except structure. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I meant isinstance, not try/except, sorry. Answer is updated.

Comment: Why isn't my answer correct? You should try it, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For `int` you can use the `isnumeric()` method

```
"1".isnumeric() #True
```

For `float`, you should try if casting to float is possible

```
 def isFloat(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Now use both these methods :

```
print("Enter a name: ")
while True:
    name = input()
    if name.isnumeric() or isFloat(name):
        print("Thats not a name!")
        print("Now please enter a name without numbers")
    elif type(name) != "":
        print("Thank you for entering your name!")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
```

Output :

```
Enter a name: 
1
Thats not a name!
Now please enter a name without numbers
1.2
Thats not a name!
Now please enter a name without numbers
abc
Thank you for entering your name!
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable is of a type, simply use `if type(VARIABLE) == TYPE:` where "VARIABLE" is your variable and TYPE is your type (such as int, float, str, etc.).

In your code, however, you may want to use `str.isnumeric()` as it will return `True` when there are numerical values in the string. To check if ANY characters are numeric, do `if all([not char.isnumeric() for char in list(STRING)]):` where "STRING" is your user's input. This checks if every character in the string is **not** numeric and returns `True` when this is the case.